# Embed Command (Colors) (discord.js-commando)

Tags: node.js, discord.js, commando

I've got a problem about an Embed Command, I am trying to let users choose color codes in this Embed Command, But this is an error I'm having: `RangeError: Argument type "colorcode" isn't registered.` .

My Code:

```
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class EmbedCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'embed',
            group: 'extra commands',
            memberName: 'embed',
            description: 'Replies with the text you provide, But in Embed.',
            args: [
                {
                    key:"text",
                    prompt:"What Should the Embed Say?",
                    type:"string",
                },
                {
                    key:"color",
                    prompt:"What Color should the Embed be? (Use Color Codes.). Use RANDOM for Random Color. (Must Be All Caps!).",
                    type:'colorcode',
                }
            ]
        });    
    }

    run(msg, { text }) {
        msg.delete();
        let embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(text)
        .setColor(color)
        msg.embed(embed)
    }
};
```

.

Does anyone know how to replace `colorcode`?

Comment: Here you can find more informations about the default args types: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/class/CommandoRegistry?scrollTo=registerDefaultTypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `type:'colorcode',` use `type: 'string',` and don't forget to change:

`run(msg, { text }) {` to `run(msg, { text, color }) {`.

You could also go to the [Repository](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/issues) of `discord.js Commando` and create a [Issue/Feature Request](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/issues) to recommend adding a new type for `Color/ColorResolveable`.

Comment: That doesn't work. The Bot just told me: 

An error occurred while running the command: `ReferenceError: color is not defined`

.

Comment: If your Question was solved use the greem tick left to the answer to mark your question as resolved.